# pip install pypdf2 SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, pypdf

I've installed Python 3.12(64-bit) and wanted to run pypdf2, for import the details to excel.

But when I typed `pip install pypdf2`, it's wrong.

```
>>> pip install pypdf2

  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install pypdf2

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: Looks like you entered this in the Python shell. You have to run `pip` from your systems shell.

Comment: @Matthias I think you are right

Answer (score 1):

syntax error show you are not in shell, you are in python shell

accord https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/

the install cmd should be

```bash
pip install PyPDF2
```